# Neo4j export whole database to JSON_LINES, ARRAY_JSON, JSON or JSON_ID_AS_KEYS

Tags: arrays, json, neo4j, export

I tried to use an APOC procedure from [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.export/apoc.export.json.all/) to export the DB using the following:

```
CALL apoc.export.json.all("all.json",{useTypes:true})
```

I can successfuly export to JSONL. However, I am not able to change the JSON format to other available formats such as JSON_LINES, ARRAY_JSON, JSON or JSON_ID_AS_KEYS. According to the documentation the following should work but it does not:

```
CALL apoc.export.json.all("all.json",{config:{jsonFormat:'ARRAY_JSON'}})
```

The result of above procedure is in JSONL but not ARRAY_JSON.

I have also tried the solution [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/apoc-export-json-query-jsonformat-setting-doesnt-work/35508) but did not succeed.

Cheers,

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working now in neo4j versions 4.2.x with APOC version 4.2.0.2: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/4.2.0.2/apoc-4.2.0.2-all.jar

The syntax is simpler. Notice the config is a dictionary rather than a nested dictionary. See my sample below.

```
OLD: CALL apoc.export.json.all("all.json",{config:{jsonFormat:'ARRAY_JSON'}})

NEW: CALL apoc.export.json.all("all.json", {jsonFormat: 'ARRAY_JSON'})
Result:
(type is array of dictionaries)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had used the new syntax but the problem was the verson of APOC. I have replaced the APOC.jar  with the one in your post and now it is working.

Comment: The Neo4j (APOC) documentation is confusing. I have wasted a lot of time to learn the new syntax!

Comment: The documentation is not the latest so I went to the source to look for the new syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my question was changing the APOC.jar file with the latest release from [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases). I have had to update the syntax as well.

```
CALL apoc.export.json.all("all.json", {jsonFormat: 'ARRAY_JSON'})
```

You can open the plugin folder using the tree dots by the blue open button and chose Open Folder -> Plugins. Copy and paste the path showed into your file manager if it doesn't open.

In the plugin folder, you can see your APOC version on the apoc file name.